# Why pressing "stop" on your browser won't suspend JavaScript execution?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm debbuging a very sensitive tree parsing core and sometimes I accidentally write an infinite loop. Problem is, everytime this happens I have to do nothing less than kill Chrome's process and start it again. I can't even close the tab. Why won't hitting "stop" button simply halt the JavaScript execution?

Answer (score 3):

The stop button just isn't hooked up to the javascript interpeter.  The answer is basically that simple.

It's only hooked up to stop network requests by closing them down and halting further parsing or further requests generated by the loading of the page.

If you want to know why it doesn't also stop javascript execution, then you'd have to ask the browser designers/implementers (it seems a reasonable idea to me).

Answer (score 1):

The stop button closes the connection between the client and the server, throwing away any more data that may be incoming.

If the java-script execution has already began, the stop button will do nothing to stop it from running.